# Post do v-form não manda dados

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express.js, vuetify

Criei um formulário básico para ver se recebo dados na minha API utilizando o vuetify porém, ao dar o submit os dados do v-select não são enviados e não consigo compreender o motivo, já que em geral os exemplos destes formulários não fazem realmente uma requisição POST, segue trechos do código que estou utlizando:

```
 <v-form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/produtos">
  <v-text-field name="escola" v-model="name" required :rules="nameRules"></v-text-field>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectPessoa"
    :items="pessoas"
    :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="nome"
    label="itens"
    required
    name="pessoa"
    return-object
    value="id"
  ></v-select>
  <v-btn color="warning" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Trecho do código javascript:

```
data(){
    return { pessoas: [{ id: 1, nome: "sandro" },
                       { id: 2, nome: "haiden" }], 
             name: '',
             selectPessoa: null,
    }
}
```

A informação que eu digitar no v-text-field eu recebo na API node, mas a do v-select não:

Tela do formulário
[image: Tela do formulário]

Tela de log da API
[image: Tela de log da API]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente criar uma função para enviar seus dados para a API, segue o exemplo:

```html
 <v-form method="post" action="onSubmit()">
  <v-text-field name="escola" v-model="name" required :rules="nameRules"></v-text-field>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectPessoa"
    :items="pessoas"
    :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="nome"
    label="itens"
    required
    name="pessoa"
    return-object
    value="id"
  ></v-select>
  <v-btn color="warning" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

```js
data(){
    return { pessoas: [{ id: 1, nome: "sandro" },
                       { id: 2, nome: "haiden" }], 
             name: '',
             selectPessoa: null,
    }
},

methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    /* Aqui você envia os dados para a API (this.name e this.selectPessoa)
    Aconselho você a utilizar o Axios para esta tarefa */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Seu erro está nessa linha:

`value="id"`

De acordo com a documentação de Interligação de Formulários [VueJs](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)
você tem que "bindar a id ao value" dessa forma:

`v-bind:value="id"`

Essa é a forma como o Vue referencia o Id ao Elemento.
Creio que isso resolva seu problema.

Comment: O bind para o id não funcionou pois não tenho uma propriedade id no 'data(){   }', resolvi meu problema tendo uma propriedade para campo no formulário e fazendo o post das propriedades name e selectPessoa através do axios.